# What internet browsers are able to provide text wrapping (fitting the screen) when zooming (beside Opera)?

Tags: browser, zooming

I am not sure I am using the proper terms, therefore I will exemplify them with screenshots. *Please help me improve my terminology if I am wrong.*

(I'm not sure [Browser which always allows scale/zoom?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/59717/161921) is about the same topic, as I don't grasp the meaning of terms like " viewport metatag parameters user-scalable" and "meta viewport tag".)

---

Taking a Wikipedia page:

[image]

Simply **zooming** it - whether with forced zoom enabled or not - would give this (like in Chrome), where the font size appears larger but the text body is not seen in its entirety, as it **doesn't fit the screen**:

[image]

while what I would like to see would be this - what I call text fit or text wrap, where **the font is enlarged without losing the entirety of the text body**, which in this case **fits the screen**:

[image]

---

I know this is available in Opera. I would like to know what other browsers have this feature.

Comment: Re: migration flag, [questions cannot be migrated after 60 days even by mods](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250). Feel free to repost it on [Softwarerecs.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will also try to answer my question - and update the answer if possible.

---

Beside **Opera**, which seems to provide this by default, I have seen this working in the **Yandex** browser, but not by default. I has to be enabled under ***Settings - Text zoom and auto-fit***. (It also has a feature that I personally like, of sliding horizontally across the scren to switch tabs.)

---

**UC Browser** has this text-fitting feature by default. (Another interesting feature it has is that sliding horizontally across the screen would navigate within the same tab to previously visited pages: left-to-right=Go back one page; righ-to-left=Go forward one page.)

---

Samsung Internet Browser does it too, but the font size has to be set manually in settings (it won't re-fit the page by simply zooming).